# how to record wertc encoded audio stream(in C++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, webrtc

Just as title, I am now preparing to use webrtc to record the audio data on the server side, but I found that I cannot obtain the encoded opus audio data. Another problem is that webrtc
AudioSink::OnData sample_rate is dynamic. For example, the problem I am encountering now is that it is 16000 at first, and then 48000

I had impl video record through webrtc::VideoTrackInterface::AddEncodedSink, But can’t find a similar interface on audio track ...

I add AudioSink to audio track, but when webrtc call AudioSink::OnData, I found that sample_rate param changed from 16000 at the beginning to 48000 after a while

Comment: I'm now using neteq::InsertPacketInternal get the encoded audio data

Answer (score 0):

solution: https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/tkKj4_ELQSc

1. `SetDepacketizerToDecoderFrameTransformer` onTrack:

```
receiver->SetDepacketizerToDecoderFrameTransformer(transformer);
```

2. parse payload by decoder && save `webrtc::AudioDecoder::EncodedAudioFrame` to file(by ffmpeg)